# TSQL Re-Enabling Contraints take a long time

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, constraint

Is there any way I can speed up the re-enabling of constraints?

As part of a job to update several tables in our Warehouse, which is being done out of hours, the re-enabling of constraints on said tables can take over an hour.  The rest of the job, the updates, take about 5 mins. Disabling the same constraints before the updates begin is sub second.

**EDIT**
The job in question is to update the PKs and FKs on rows of data before a given date so to prevent those records appearing in reports. A way to `soft delete` records` if you like.

Most of the table row sizes are >130m rows each except for one which is over 370m rows. The other two are smaller.

```
TableName   rows
Table_1     371255778
Table_2     131703902
Table_3     131665535
Table_4     131665535
Table_5     131665535
Table_6     131665535
Table_7     19364988
Table_8     1458800
```

I am using the following the command to disable the constraints on each table

`ALTER TABLE database.dbo.table_name        NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL;`

And the following to re-enable them again

`ALTER TABLE database.dbo.table_name        WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL;`

there are no reports or other jobs running at the same time.

Is taking so long to re-enable constraints expected behaviour or is there something that can be done to speed it up?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As expected.

For example, CHECK constraints: every row must be checked for every check constraint.

If you have 3 CHECK constraints and 370 million rows, that's 1.11 billion checks to be done in a single ALTER.

Each UNIQUE constraint must check all 370 million rows, in the same ALTER.

This is why I don't normally disable constraints in my DWs.
It takes too much time. Especially when you get to billions of rows.

Comment: Thanks, Do you have a suggestion as to how you can update rows on these tables without violating constraints?  - The job in question is to update the PKs and FKs on rows of data before a given date so to prevent those records appearing in reports. A way to `soft delete` records if you like

Comment: @Cool_Br33ze: arrange for the updates to not violate the constraints part way through. For changing PK values for rows referred to by FKs: 1. Create new rows with the new IDs, 2. Update the referring rows in other tables, 3. Remove the old rows in the parent table, all in a transaction so it doesn't get partially done if there is an error. Or in this case, let the engine do it for you by defining the FKs with `ON UPDATE CASCADE`.

Comment: @DavidSpillett I will give that approach a try. Thanks

Comment: @Cool_Br33ze: if you go with the `CASCADE` approach, be very very wary of `ON DELETE CASCADE` as that makes it incredibly easy to shoot yourself in the foot. Though in the situation described us sounds like you just need updates to be cascaded.

Comment: @DavidSpillett Do I still need a transaction if I go with the `ON UPDATE CASCADE` approach?

Comment: @Cool_Br33ze: there will be an implicit transaction around the updating of the child rows and the parent row, if there isn't already an explicit transaction defined. So no, you don't need to start one yourself unless the update is part of a larger operation that needs to be atomic.